# understand zepto.matches function

Tags: javascript, zepto

In the source code of zepto,I found that in zepto.matches function,there's a fallback perform,

```
zepto.matches = function(element, selector) {
    if (!element || element.nodeType !== 1) return false
    var matchesSelector = element.webkitMatchesSelector || element.mozMatchesSelector ||
                          element.oMatchesSelector || element.matchesSelector
    if (matchesSelector) return matchesSelector.call(element, selector)
    // fall back to performing a selector:
    var match, parent = element.parentNode, temp = !parent
    if (temp) (parent = tempParent).appendChild(element)
    match = ~zepto.qsa(parent, selector).indexOf(element)
    temp && tempParent.removeChild(element)
    return match
  }
```

despite the normal matchSelector way,I'm quite curious about the fallback,why it add **~** in front of this:

`~zepto.qsa(parent, selector).indexOf(element)`

```
   document.getElementById("test");
   $.zepto.matches(a,"#test") // -1
```

it returns -1 , is it right or am I missing something?

Comment: That is the NOT bitwise operator. That's a little hack that is perfect for `indexOf` calls. If the value returned from `indexOf` is `-1` (meaning it wasn't found in the collection/string), `~-1` is `0`...which is logically the same as `false`. Any other value returned from `indexOf` (greater than -1), `~value` will be truthy (meaning it was found). So it's an easy way to put `indexOf` in a comparison

Answer (score 0):

It's the [Bitwise NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7E_%28Bitwise_NOT%29). In this case it's used to have a boolean return value for `indexOf`: the `indexOf` methods (array, string), returns -1 if a match is not found, and the position if a match is found. The position can be also 0, of course. So using the bitwise NOT operator:

```
console.log(~-1); // 0
console.log(~0) // -1
console.log(~1) // -2
// and so on
```

So because in JS `0` is considered as a "Falsy" value, and any other number – except `NaN` – is a "Truthy" value, having `~zepto.qsa(parent, selector).indexOf(element)` will returns `0` if the element is NOT found, and therefore can be thread has a "Falsy" value in the code:

```
var isFound = ~zepto.qsa(parent, selector).indexOf(element);

if (isFound) {
  // do something
}
```

However, in that case I would expect the zepto methods to return a real boolean, because it's an API method. In this such case, I would prefer use simply:

```
match = zepto.qsa(parent, selector).indexOf(element) > -1;
```

Or

```
match = !!~zepto.qsa(parent, selector).indexOf(element);
```

The double `!` it's used to have the proper Boolean representation: if `indexOf` returns `-1`, the `~` transform it in `0`, then the first `!` in `true`, and the second ones in `false`, that is the Boolean value we expect for "not found".

The Bitwise NOT it's also used for some other tricks, like this one:

```
var words = ["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"];
var frequency = words.reduce(function(freq, word) {
    freq[word] = -~freq[word];
    return freq;
}, {})
```

This code returns an object like `{a:1, b:3, c:1}`; it basically counts the frequency of the same string value in an array. Here the Bitwise NOT it's used with the [Unary Negation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29) to have an incremental counter: so if `freq[word]` is `undefined` – because this word is not yet in the "dictionary" – then the `~undefined` is `-1`, and with the unary negation becames `1`. The next time we'll have `-~1`, and therefore `- -2`, so `2`; then `-~2` will be `3` and so on.

The bitwise operators are really useful, but also easier to be abused. In some cases are necessary (For instance, the [Zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) it's currently the only way in JS to have a substitute of `ToUint32`) they're not, and they could lead to code hard to read.

But they're definitely worthy to be known.